# Spring JPA Cascade.ALL won't delete parent object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I'm following this "Bidirectional many-to-many with link entity lifecycle" tutorial here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many. However, I'm using Spring JPA instead of Entity Manager. When I delete an address using repository interface, it isn't not deleting the PersonAddress record even though I've cascade ALL. It's giving me Foreign Key constraint exception.

"Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKCYC1KRSXQELKM4UWH65AVIJ23: PUBLIC.PERSON_ADDRESS FOREIGN KEY(ADDRESS_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ADDRESS(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:"

My classess are below.

```
@Entity(name = "Address")
public class Address  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String street;

@Column(name = "number")
private String number;

private String postalCode;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "address", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<PersonAddress> owners = new ArrayList<>();
```

PersonAddress.java

```
 @Entity(name = "PersonAddress")
    public class PersonAddress implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;
```

Person.java

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
public class Person{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    private String registrationNumber;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<PersonAddress> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
```

Test method that deletes the address after Person and Address are associated. This should delete a record in PersonAddress because Address has Cascade.ALL but it isn't happening. What am I missing?

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testDeleteAddressAfterPatronAdd() {

Person person1 = new Person("ABC-123");
Person person2 = new Person("DEF-456");
Address address1 = new Address("12th Avenue", "12A", "4005A");
Address address2 = new Address("18th Avenue", "18B", "4007B");

Person savedPerson1 = personRepository.save(person1);
Person savedPerson2 = personRepository.save(person2);       
Address savedAddress1 = addressRepository.save(address1);
Address savedAddress2 = addressRepository.save(address2);
personRepository.flush();       
addressRepository.flush();

PersonAddress personAddress1 = new PersonAddress(savedPerson1, savedAddress1);      
PersonAddress personAddress2 = new PersonAddress(savedPerson2, savedAddress2);
savedPerson1.getAddresses().add(personAddress1);
savedPerson2.getAddresses().add(personAddress2);
personRepository.flush();       
addressRepository.flush();

Address loadedAddress1 = addressRepository.findById(savedAddress1.getId());
loadedAddress1.getOwners();
addressRepository.delete(loadedAddress1);       
addressRepository.flush();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not correctly maintaining the two sides of the association. `personAddress1` referenced `address1`, but `address1` doesn't have any element in its list of owners.

So, when you're deleting `address1`, Hibernate doesn't cascade the deletion to any owner, since it there isn't any in the list. And the deletion thus fails because you're trying to delete an `Address` that is referenced by a `PersonAddress`, though a FK constraint.

Comment: Should I add personAddress1 to address1 as well? I get that problem would happen when I try to delete the address1 object that's currently in session. However, I'm reading the address from the database and doing a getOwners(). Wouldn't that load owners into loadedAddress1 from the database? Correct me if I'm wrong, that's why I thought we've Cascade on Address to PersonAddress.

Comment: All your work is done in the same session, opened when the transactional method is called, and closed when it returns. So you're not reading anything from the database here. findById() returns the entity from the first-level cache, that you populated when saving the entity before.